# обработка html страницы

Tags: php

помогите как из этого:

```
$re = '/catalog\/category.+cid=[0-9]+&/';
$str = '/catalog/category/vechernie-platya/?cid=50103022&';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
print_r($matches);
```

получить значение `[0-9]` то есть `50103022`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается решения очень простое:

```
$re = '/catalog\/category.+cid=([0-9]+)&/';
$str = '/catalog/category/vechernie-platya/?cid=50103022&';
preg_match($re, $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Ставите вокруг `[0-9]+` скобочки --> `([0-9]+)`, чтобы была отдельная группа захвата для искомого числа. Результат пробуете наблюдать в элементе массива с индексом `1`, так как это первая группа захвата из-за отсутствия остальных.

Comment: сделал только получил не то что хотел: https://repl.it/@megaPhp/ElaborateSuddenInexpectatumpleco

Comment: Ну вы блин даёте) Парсите целую страницу, а нам говорите, что url...

Comment: а мне что целую страницу сюда выкладывать?

Comment: Достаточно упомянуть в вопросе, что субъект обработки - html страница, к тому же, требуемого содержимое - часть js-кода на ней

Comment: Извините, не знал как правильно задать вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, лучше разобрать запрос, как запрос:

```
$url = '/catalog/category/vechernie-platya/?cid=50103022&';
$s_query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($s_query, $query);

var_dump($query['cid']);
```

Comment: а если `cid` встречается несколько раз? тогда буду получать последний `cid` проблема в том что нужный `cid` встречается именно в этом `/catalog/category/vechernie-platya/?cid=50103022&`